# GNOME/KDE Linux entirely in RAM?

Tags: performance, gnome, ramdisk

I'd like to have very responsive linux but I also like modern, elegant and functional desktops like gnome or kde, not the lightweight ones like xfce or lxde.

Once I tried PuppyLinux and was impressed by the responsivity when I clicked an application.

In my Ubuntu, it bothers me much when I click chromium and must wait 5 seconds of disk flashing until main window appears. Or evolution or anything else.

Is it possible to make GNOME or KDE run entirely in RAM like PuppyLinux (of course, I mean frequently used applications and services, not all) if you have enough of it? I don't care if boot time is longer. I tried using "preload" but it didn't help much.

Comment: i would look into a realtime kernel or BSD

Comment: As far as I remember I already tried BSD and was a bit disappointed due to lack of some features. But things could change, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can. [This tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/) explains how to create a RAM Disk in Linux, setting up memory as a hard drive partition. The problem, though, is that -I think- if you reboot or shut down the computer, you lose everything.

My advice: buy a SSD. There are some really good ones -small, around 32-40 GB- under $100, but you usually don't need more for your root partition and all the apps. Everything else could be on a traditional, cheap hard drive. You'll notice how read/write times really make a difference. And boot times are really nice, too.

Comment: I'm afraid RAM disk isn't a way for me, it would be too complicated for me to figure what should go there and how to do it at boot. Thanks for suggestion, though.